# How to calculate Car "Distance Till Empty" without knowing the fuel level

Tags: obd-ii

I've Renault Duster RxZ. I would like to calculate the DTE(Distance till Empty) which is based on the "how much fuel the car has" and the "mileage of the car" ?
Currently the OBD doesn't return anything when i send the PID "01 2F", it says "NO DATA".

Is there any other way to calculate the DTE ?

Comment: Not sure there is a way to calculate the remaining distance if you can't find out how much fuel is left.

Comment: Is this a diesel?

Comment: @Alex Yes, Diesel

Answer (score 1):

You can estimate DTE. Fill your tank. If you know your capacity, you now know how much is there. If you know your fuel economy, multiply capacity by mpg and that's roughly your DTE.

Comment: If i know how much is there, they its easy to calculate, but what if i don't know how much is there ?